# How do I delete the currentItem of a QTreeWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5

The title says it all. I can't find anything useful on it. How do I do it?

How do I get currentItem's index or data?

How do I use `self.treeWidget.currentItem.().data()`?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take your time to follow the [tour], read [ask] good questions, and consider that you should only ask one question per post (while you're asking 3). That said, have you studied the documentation about [QTreeWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html) and [QTreeWidgetItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html)? (before you ask, yes, I *do* know that's the C++ documentation, but 99% of functions are and behave exactly as they do in PyQt).

Comment: I did examine the docs

Comment: And? Because, if you want to delete an item from the view, doing a simple page search for the keywords "remove" or "delete" I can get a few, but very interesting results. And if you want to get or set the text displayed on an item, there are also other few and interesting results for the keyword "text". Sorry, but your "examine the docs" doesn't seem that thorough.

Comment: I prob didn't search it with good keywords. My bad. I checked their functions though. I can't find anything on deleting the currentItem still. Idk why.

Comment: It's not view it's qtreewidget btw

Comment: It is a widget that allows visual representation of a data model, so it **is** a view: QTreeWidget is based on QTreeView, which inherits from QAbstractItemView, and that's the base class of the [Model/View](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) pattern used in Qt. That said there's obviously no function to directly delete the current item (conceptually speaking is not a very good function), but there are functions for deleting a given item: since you already know the function to get the current item, have you considered to use those functions together?

Comment: I guessed they're two separate objects. I'm dumb. What functions do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current row index :

```
self.treeWidget.indexFromItem(self.treeWidget.currentItem(), 0).row()
```

to get the text :

```
self.treeWidget.currentItem().text(column)
```

Comment: To add on to the solution, what I did was I made an array. Whenever I made an entry, I insert the name to the array( Should be a value that will not be repeated, which is time in my app). And when I want to delete the entry, I loop through the array with an index, checking if the column data matched the entry data. If it did, I did array.pop(index) and then update the qtreewidget. The way I did the update function was by clearing the qtreewidget and looping through the array while inserting items.

Comment: You could prob also just use self.treeWidget.takeTopLevelItem(self.treeWidget.indexFromItem(self.treeWidget.currentItem(), 0).row()) but I wanted to delete the data from my array anyways